# There was an error while trying to load the gem 'ahoy_matey'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm not actually a ruby dev, I'm just trying to get development environment setup from a project and I'm having a world of trouble getting the gems in order so I can load up the server. I do mostly front-end work. Anyways, my error is:

```
There was an error while trying to load the gem 'ahoy_matey'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `hours' for 4:Fixnum
```

I've been searching google for last two days and can't come across anyone experiencing this issue with "ahoy_matey" gem. I get this error when trying to launch the server or rake migrations.

Ruby 1.9.3

Rails 3.2.13

mysql2 0.3.17

Any help is appreciated.

Full trace:

```
Bundler::GemRequireError: There was an error while trying to load the gem    'ahoy_matey'.
Gem Load Error is: undefined method `hours' for 4:Fixnum
Backtrace for gem load error is:
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/ahoy_matey-1.1.0/lib/ahoy.rb:43:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/ahoy_matey-1.1.0/lib/ahoy.rb:39:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/ahoy_matey-1.1.0/lib/ahoy_matey.rb:1:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/ahoy_matey-1.1.0/lib/ahoy_matey.rb:1:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/Rakefile:5:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:28:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:689:in `raw_load_rakefile'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:94:in `block in load_rakefile'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:93:in `load_rakefile'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:77:in `block in run'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:176:in `standard_exception_handling'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/lib/rake/application.rb:75:in `run'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/rake-11.1.2/bin/rake:33:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/rake:23:in `load'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/rake:23:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
Bundler Error Backtrace:
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:90:in `rescue in block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:85:in `block (2 levels) in require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `each'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:81:in `block in require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `each'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:70:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/gems/bundler-1.12.1/lib/bundler.rb:102:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/config/application.rb:7:in `'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/Rakefile:5:in `require'
/home/sirtastic/projects/dataraptor/Rakefile:5:in `'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
/home/sirtastic/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p551@dr/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `'
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.2.13'

    gem 'mysql2'#, '~> 0.3.11'
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3' # Because SCSS is compiled for embedded quoters

    # Gems used only for assets and not required
    # in production environments by default.
    group :assets do
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

    # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    gem 'therubyracer', :platforms => :ruby
    gem 'execjs', :platforms => :ruby

    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails', '~> 3.0.4'
    gem 'jquery-ui-rails', '~> 4.0.5'
    gem 'jquery_datepicker'

    group :production do
    gem 'pry', require:false
    end

    group :development, :test do
    gem 'capybara', :require => false
    gem 'database_cleaner', :require => false                # for use with capybara tests
    gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.1'          # for generating test models
    gem 'factory_girl_rails', require:false
    gem 'forgery'                         # for generating test data
    gem 'pry'
    gem 'pry_debug'
    gem 'pry-nav'
    gem 'spork-rails', platform: [:mswin, :mingw] # Fast rpsec testing on Windows
    #### DON'T JUST ADD GEMS TO THE END OF THIS LIST! ALPHABETIZE! ###
    end

    group :development do
    gem 'thin'              # Sane development server
    gem 'bullet'            # for identifying areas to speed up database queries
    gem 'meta_request'      # for chrome rails-panel
    gem 'rack-mini-profiler', require:false
    #### DON'T JUST ADD GEMS TO THE END OF THIS LIST! ALPHABETIZE! ###
    end

    group :test do
    gem 'launchy', :require => false
    gem 'rspec-rails'
    gem "selenium-webdriver", "~> 2.40.0" # for AJAX testing
    gem 'shoulda', :require => false
    gem 'simplecov', :require => false    # Test coverage
    gem 'timecop'
    gem 'vcr', '~> 2.9.3'#'~> 2.5.0'
    gem "webmock", '~> 1.10.2'
    #### DON'T JUST ADD GEMS TO THE END OF THIS LIST! ALPHABETIZE! ###
    end

    group :dev, :release, :development do
    gem 'better_errors'
    gem 'binding_of_caller' # supports better errors by providing IDE in browser when error occurs
    end

    gem 'activeuuid', '>= 0.5.0'
    gem 'ahoy_matey', '1.1.0'       #needs this exact version in order to output UUIDs consistently. the next version after does not.
    gem 'american_date'             # by default, dates are parsed/formatted with American style
    gem 'angularjs-rails', '~> 1.0.7'
    gem 'attr_encrypted', '~> 1.2'  # encrypt activerecord attributes in db
    gem 'authlogic', '~> 3.2'       # user login
    gem 'aws-sdk'
    gem 'capistrano', require: false# deployment of application
    gem 'capistrano-ext', require: false
    gem 'carrierwave'               # file upload solution
    gem 'daemons'                   # used for running delayed_job jobs
    gem 'encryptor', '~> 1.1'       # handle encryption of ActiveRecord fields
    gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.0'
    gem 'faraday'                   # REST client for interfacing with external APIs
    gem 'faraday_middleware'
    gem 'fog', '~> 1.22'            # for Amazon Web Services cloud storage
    gem 'formatador', '~> 0.2'      # This shouldn't need to be here. It is/was a dependency for fog-core, but it wasn't getting bundled (for some reason), so raking assets:precompile consistently failed. 2014-09-17.
    gem 'haml', '~> 4.0.3'
    gem 'holidays', '~> 2.1.0'
    gem 'httpi', '~> 2.2.7'
    gem 'json', '~> 1.8.1'          # Specified so as to 'safely' conduct an update for the sake of stripe gem (2014-05-21)
    gem 'liquid', '~> 2.5.0'        # rendering templates, such as Marketing::Email::Template
    gem 'mini_magick'               # photo resizing
    gem 'momentjs-rails'
    gem 'multi_xml'
    gem 'paperclip', '~> 3.5.0'     # handle file attachments to activerecord
    gem "paypal-recurring"
    gem 'nested_form'
    gem 'rails3-jquery-autocomplete'# supports autocomplete fields
    gem 'redis'                     # for publishing
    gem 'remotipart', '~> 1.0'      # enables multipart form submissions over ajax
    gem 'ruby-saml', '~> 1.0.0'
    gem 'rvm-capistrano', require: false # for deploying to servers where multiple rubies are available
    gem 'safe_attributes'           # takes care of attribute name collisions w/ ActiveRecord (we use 'delay')
    gem 'savon', '~> 2.7'
    gem "select2-rails"             # makes an autocomplete select box, compatible with x-editable
    gem 'sidekiq', '~> 2.17.0'      # handles background/delayed jobs
    gem 'spreadsheet', require: false
    gem "stripe", '~> 1.11.0'
    gem 'tinymce-rails', '>= 4.0.8' # version 4.0.8 includes important bug fixes
    gem 'transaction_retry'         # Catch mysql deadlock and try again
    gem 'tzip', '~> 0.0.4'          # Find timezone by zip code
    gem 'whenever', require: false  # handles scheduled tasks
    gem 'wicked_pdf'                # creates pdfs from html (is a wrapper for wkhtmltopdf)
    gem 'will_paginate', '~> 3.0'   # paginates index pages for activerecord
    gem 'wkhtmltopdf-binary'        # the backend linux tool that creates pdfs from html using QT Webkit rendering engine
    #### DON'T JUST ADD GEMS TO THE END OF THIS LIST! ALPHABETIZE! ###
```

Comment: Probably missing the `activesupport` gem... can you add your Gemfile and `config/application.rb` ?

Comment: I have gem activesupport (3.2.13) installed.. working on gemlist for you

Comment: Added the gemlist to original post. Can't post application.rb, potentially sensitive info?

Comment: To be clear, you're getting the error when starting the app with something like `rails server` or `rails console`?

Comment: Rails server via 'rails s'

Comment: A thought.. on a working environment I have mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.30 (and everything is working). On this non-working environment I have mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.12.  Any idea if this dist version makes any difference here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might be requiring your bundle before requiring rails. If you have these two lines in your `application.rb` file, they need to be in this order:

```
require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

Comment: I'm requiring rails/all on line  3 and the bundler after on line 7. Don't think this is the issue though thanks for input!

Answer (score 0):

So I see you're running just `rails s`. I know this question is old but maybe this might help someone else. So the command you want to be running is:

`bundle exec rails s`

`bundle exec` executes a command in the context of the bundle.

This command executes the command, making all gems specified in the `Gemfile` available to `require` in Rails.

Essentially, if you would normally have run something like `rspec spec/my_spec.rb`, and you want to use the gems specified in the `Gemfile` and installed via `bundle install`, you should run `bundle exec rspec spec/my_spec.rb`.

Note that `bundle exec` does not require that an executable is available on your shell's `$PATH`.

[Source](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-exec.1.html)